# Display a dynamic bubble on a link hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I hope you can help me with this problem :). I'm looking for a script which allows me to display a dynamic bubble on a link hover by jQuery.

I would to to define a hidden div with the content and display it on a hover of certain link (always in the middle of that link and it should disappear when you leave the link OR the box with your cursor).

Something like this (sorry for such poor illustration :D):

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch out this: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

styleable with css (image free) plugin for jquery.

Comment: Looks fine, thank you... I'll try it if this one fails :) http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Comment: the one i suggested seems to be more used -> documented, anyway  I didn't try personally it, please let me know how yours work so if i will have to use a similar plugin i know what to do :)

Comment: Sorry, I answered in wrong order, your solution looks more "convenient" to me :))

Answer (score 3):

You should try some plugin, like this one [tooltip](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/). I am using it for few years without any problem.

Hope this helps